Flutter pusher_channels_flutter It comes to the wrong person
I couldn't figure out what the problem was all day.
I am using the pusher_channels_flutter package.
I have sent messages, everything is working fine.
When reading a message by an opponent, I need to indicate that the message has been read. But it is marked as read not by the sender, but by the one who read it.
What's the problem?
PusherInit(channelName: 'private-Chat.${widget.idChat}', eventName: 'MessageSent').onConnectPressed();
PusherInit(channelName: 'private-Message.${widget.idChat}', eventName: 'MessageRead').onConnectPressed();

PusherInit(channelName: 'private-Chat.${widget.idChat}', eventName: 'client-MessageSent').onTriggerEventPressed(widget.idChat.toString(), currentUser.id.toString());

